# Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex SDK Tools 22.3

Tags: android

Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode

Latest ADT, Latest SDK Tools (22.3).

I Tried :

1. Clean/rebuild
2. Update Eclipse
3. Delete bin and gen folders
4. Restart Eclipse
5. Mannually build with Ant
6. Plus some other stuff

All my projects are now targeting API lvl 19.

I have no clue what to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The multiple dex files error just tell you that you are including the same class file from different sources. Restarting Eclipse or building with Ant will therefore not help as your project setup is just invalid.

As you do not specify what jars you are using, there is no way to tell what is going on for sure.

However, the newest Google Play library includes ads and my guess would be that you are including both Admob and Google Play Services which apparently contain the same classes. In that case you should migrate your code to use the Google Play Service ads and remove the admob jar from your project.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I didn't had any problems before updating ...

The thing is that I use DFPAdView, and it's not available if I remove GoogleAdMobSdk-6.4.1.jar

Comment: In my case - I'm not using ads or AdMob in the app at all!  Still that error shows up.  How stupid is that???

Comment: It's still the same issue, just related to different dependencies: you are including the same class file twice from different dependencies...

Comment: What if we want to show ads on android 2.1 and above. There if we use the adView from play services library it crashes.

Comment: @botteaap But Google play service is available for 2.2 and newer versions only and my app supports 2.1 as well.What should I do to handle this?

Comment: perfect ans. with description !

Answer (score 13):

*Right click on project name and select the Build Path.

*Then select Configure Build Path.

*From Java Build Path select the tab Order and Export.

*Uncheck the .jar libraries.

The error is generally due to multiplicity in libraries.

Answer (score 7):

Have you checked your xml files? I have the same Problem (and it is not solved yet) and I forgot to change the adView attribute from:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
```

to

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
```

then you should also chech your

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.ads"
```

(dunno if this is right though...)

Edit:
Found this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

(Source: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals)

Edit2:

Ok now I solved my Problem. I am such an Idiot...
Well I integrated the AdMob SDK in the services library... I deleted it and everything was great again! So delete the services_lib, download it and import again that should work I guess. Good Luck!

Comment: I'm not using XML ads, they are all generated and added at runtime

Answer (score 2):

Worked fine after delete the "GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar" from my project.
Dont forget to add the Google Play Services as Library to your app.
Regards!

Answer (score 2):

It's because Google Play Service has google Ads in it.
That's why you're having multiple dex error.

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are using google play service as well, then there is a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse project properties->Java build path->Order and export

Uncheck Android private libraries.

Do not use jar file and library project together of google play service lib in your project.