# Error on Adding GoogleMap to My Android Application

Tags: android

I Made pinning required place on Google map by means of `latitude` and `longitude`. It's working very well. When I make a new workspace and import all these to that. Then I got errors like this.

```
Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode;
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex SDK Tools 22.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734152/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-unable-to-execute-dex-sdk-tools-22-3)

Comment: check in buildpath that you added gmap api twice

Comment: Thank You. I got the proper solution when i perform following steps. *Right click on project name and select the Build Path.

*Then select Configure Build Path.

*From Java Build Path select the tab Order and Export.

*Uncheck the .jar libraries.

The error is generally due to multiplicity in libraries.